# how to print the value for the Node of xml on console in blackberry

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, xml-parsing, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have created the NODES for parsing but i dont know how to display the values within that NODE. hear is my NODE for that i want t\o print the value in console of eclipse.

```
enter code here

      for(int j=0; j<tempList.getLength(); j++){
      if(tempList.item(j).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("btitle")){
      tempNode = tempList.item(j);
      tempNode2 = ((NodeList)tempNode.getChildNodes()).item(0);
      bean.setTitle(tempNode2.getNodeValue().trim());

 //        System.out.println("Node Value or title" +bean.getTitle() );
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to print the value of the node and all its children or just the node itself?

Comment: all,node and its children also.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here for pretty printing an XML:

[XML Writer class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/xml/jaxp/XMLWriter.html)

The code sample at the top of the page shows you how you can pretty print an xml given an output stream. To get a pretty-printed output stream using DOM, see the answer here by Ted_Hopp:

[DOM Printing](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-create-xml-file-using-RIM-api/td-p/279850)